# django runscript No (valid) module for script 'myscriptnamehere.py' found

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Python version: 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.
Runscript --version 1.10.4

My scripts worked previously.  I'm not sure when they stopped, but now no scripts will run with the command **python manage.py runscript myscriptname.py**.  I've stripped a test script down to print a single line, with no imports and it still errors out.
Example script:

```
def run(*args):
    print "hello"
```

I consistently get the error "No (valid) module for script 'myscripthere.py' found".  When I use the -v2 option I can see it check all the various apps and directories and then it fails.

If I insert a line I know should throw an error, it throws the error for that line. i.e.:

```
def run(*args):
    this line is garbage and will thrown an error
    print "hello"
```

Comment: What's the location of the script? Please show the output when you run with  `-v2`

Comment: The script is in the scripts directory of my application.  I've tried running it from the root of the application and from within the scripts directory.  I get the same result either way.  With the v2 option I get the below output (I've omitted some of the stuff in the middle as it's all the same just listing specific directories within my app):

Check for django.contrib.auth.scripts.myscriptname.py
...
Check for raven.contrib.django.scripts.myscriptname.py
Check for myscriptname.scripts.py
Check for myscriptname.py
No (valid) module for script 'myscriptname.py' found

Comment: Try `python manage.py runscript myscriptname` (without `.py`).

Comment: That did it.  I just needed to drop the .py suffix.  I must have had my documentation from previous runs messed up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn’t include `.py` when specifying the script to run. Change your command to:

```
python manage.py runscript myscriptname
```